# Get only one record from child table

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi I am using the following query to select only one file from child table that has a matching id with the parent table but its giving error. please help

```
    $query = $this -> db -> query("select post.id AS PostID, post.*, 
post_files.* from post LEFT JOIN post_files ON post.category_id='1' AND 
post.id=(SELECT * FROM post_files WHERE post.id=post_files.post_id LIMIT 1)");
```

post is the table where main information of posts will be saved and all the files likes images will be saved in post_files table. So i want to get only one file from post_files.

Answer (score 0):

You have error in sub query
It should be

> SELECT post.id AS PostID, post.*,MIN(post_files.id) as file_id FROM post LEFT JOIN post_files ON post.id=post_files.post_id GROUP BY post.id HAVVING post.category_id='1';

Comment: but its getting all the record from post_files table i want only one row of each matching record

Comment: right now i have 2 posts and both posts have multiple images this query is getting all post files of first post not second

Comment: please specify your tables with fields and expected output.